# Free y axis in ggplot and plotnine

Tags: python, r, ggplot2, plotnine

I need help with a plot in python. I used the example dataset mpg.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from plotnine import *
from plotnine.data import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

mpg.head()
mpg = mpg.loc[(mpg.manufacturer=="audi") | (mpg.manufacturer=="jeep") ]
p = ggplot(aes(x='displ', y='manufacturer'), mpg)
```

I obtain this plot: [image]
But I would like the shapes are free in y axis (because I have elements with overlapping), for example something like this:
[image]

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use position_jitter to add some randomness along the vertical direction.

```
+ geom_point(position=position_jitter(width=0, height=0.3))
```